# Ionic cordova run android --prod returns whitescreen only in latest version of typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, version

I have an **App** where I used older version of typescript in that specific project. Currently using **2.8.3 tsc** but when I switched from **3.1.4 tsc** `console.log` is not working anymore and when I try to run it on a **production mode** it just renders a white screen as always.

But when I try to lower the version of my **tsc** to **2.8.3** it is now working again.

Now what I want to happen is to upgrade my **typescript** version because I want to use [ngrx/store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) and [ngrx/effects](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects) which requires a higher version of **tsc**. I try other versions that is a little bit higher but still not working.

What I did to test this crazy experiment is I created two dummy ionic projects. One project is using **2.8.3** and tryo to run some `console.log` and running it on **production** is still working fine.

But on the other hand or the other project that is using **3.1.4 tsc** running some `console.log` is not working anymore and it just renders a **whitescreen** in **production**

Btw here is my **info info** below

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.0-rc.13 (/home/clifford/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0, browser 5.0.4

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v6.12.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 4.6.1
   OS                : Linux 4.13

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : /home/clifford/Android/Sdk
```

Any thoughts on this? 
Appreciate if someone could help to get it working fine on latest versions.

Comment: are you using ionic 4?

Comment: nope only **Ionic 3**

Comment: ionic 4 only added support for angular 7, which internally uses typescript 3.1.x. First upgrade your application to Ionic 4 and then upgrade the typescript.

Comment: Ohhh but I didn't want the big project on **ionic 4** I only switched higher versions of **tsc** because of ngrx/effect does not work on lower version. I will create a new question about this can you help me?

Comment: you can use ngrx/store in ionic 3. why you need to upgrade typscript ver?

Comment: ngrx/effects problem here is the link of the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491165/ngrx-effects-on-lower-version-of-typescript-doesnt-work

Comment: try using lower version which has support for typescript 2.6 support npm install @ngrx/store@5.2.0 @ngrx/effects@5.2.0 --save