# Ngrx effects on lower version of typescript doesn't work

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an **Ionic 3 App** where I use [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) and [ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects). But each time I try to run the app it sais this error below:

> TypeScript Error A computed property name in a type literal must
>   directly refer to a built- in symbol. ...: Cannot find name 'any'.

which refers to this folder in my node modules **node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/on_run_effect.d.ts**

to this block of code below:

```
export declare function isOnRunEffects(sourceInstance: {
    [onRunEffectsKey]?: onRunEffectsFn;
}): sourceInstance is OnRunEffects;
```

This can be fix by installing higher version of **typescript** but as of now currently I am using **2.6.1** but when I upgrade it to a higher version of **typescript** my app doesn't work on **production** and even the `console.log` methods are not working.

here is my **ionic info** below:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.0-rc.13 (/home/clifford/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : browser 5.0.4

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v6.12.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 4.6.1
   OS                : Linux 4.13

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : /home/clifford/Android/Sdk
```

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you are using latest version which is internally uses typescript 3.1.x. Please try to downgrade to the specific version (5.2.0) for typescript 2.6.x. and check it.

```
npm install @ngrx/store@5.2.0 @ngrx/effects@5.2.0 --save
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. But there are still problem on production. I think it is more of a ngrx/store file structure and effects.